# map the url in such a way that it dont show file extension and querystring

Tags: asp.net, .net

i want to show person's name in place of id in URL for example

```
http://MyWebSite/Doc/Home.aspx?UID=6
to
http://MyWebSite/Doc/Harry
```

is it possible with url re-writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with System.Web.Routing...  taken help from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37917/URL-rewriting-using-ASP-NET-routing article

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to use the [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx)

It allows you to control how to map virtual resources.

The request for `http://MyWebSite/Doc/Harry` would first come to you and if you say the path is virtual (by overriding a `FileExists` method), the asp.net engine will come to you for the contents of the file (override the `GetFile` method).

This code project article on [Creating Custom Virtual Path Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16848/Creating-Custom-Virtual-Path-Provider-in-ASP-Net-2) should guide you. It implements exactly what you want.